# Finding optima of functions via newton´s method in R

Tags: r, new-operator

We need to find the local extrema/optima of the following function with its derivatives and the newton's method in R. Here is the task and my algorithm. Unfortunately I don't get any result.

Root finding algorithms can also be used for finding local optima of functions. Recall that for a differentiable function f a necessary condition for x∗ to be an optimum is f′(x∗) = 0. Consider the function

f(x)=x3 −3x2 +1+100sin(x+1)

on the interval I = [−6,6]. Use newton root2 to find the roots of the derivative f′ on I, then classify all stationary points of f as local minimum, local maximum, or inflection point. At which point f attains its global maximum on I? Initiate your algorithm in different starting values and discuss in which situations the algorithm gets stuck in local optima (in the sense that it does not find the global optimum).

````
f3 <- function(x0) {
  x0^3 - 3*x0^2 + 1 + 100*sin(x0+1)
}

f3_prime <- function(x0) {
  3*x0^2 - 6*x0 + 100*cos(x0+1)
}

f3_prime_prime <- function(x0) {
  6*x0 - 6 - 100*-sin(x0+1)
}```



# algorithm

eps<- 1e-6
n_max <- 50
x0 <- -6

newton_root2 <- function(f3, f3_prime, f3_prime_prime, x0, nmax=50, eps) {
  x0 <- -6
  n <- 0
  while (n <= n_max) {
    n <- n + 1
    y0 <- f3(x0)
    y1 <- f3_prime(x0)
    y2 <- f3_prime_prime(x0)
    if (y1 < eps) {
      break(0)
    }
    x1 <- x0 - (y0/y1) * (1 + (y0 * y2) / (2 * y1)^2)
    if (abs((x0 - x1) / x1) < eps) {
      print('convergent')
      break(0)
    }
    x0 <- x1
    print(paste(label = 'iterations', n, label = 'approximate root', x0))
  }
````

Comment: Shouldn't `y1 < eps` be `abs(y1) < eps`? Also -- why have a function that *prints* its result rather than *returns* it? Functions which print are much less useful than functions which return values which can be used by other code.

Comment: When I run your code (after supplying the missing `}` at the bottom) I get output when I call the function. Did you *call* the function? All your posted code does is define it.